# Find the measure of the unknown angle

Tags: geometry

[image]
My turn:
In triangle $ADC$
$$\frac{AC}{\sin{x}}=\frac{DC}{\sin{100}}= \frac{AD}{sin{(80-x)}}$$Then
$$AC=AB = \frac{DC \sin{x}}{\sin{100}}$$
In triangle $BDC$
$$\frac{DC}{\sin{140}}= \frac{BD}{\sin{(40-x)}}$$
Then
$$BD = \frac{DC \sin{(40-x)}}{sin140}$$
But $$AD = AB + BD$$
Then
$$\frac{AB + BD}{\sin{(80-x)}}= \frac{DC}{\sin{100}}$$
$$\frac{\frac{DC \sin{(40-x)}}{\sin{140}}+\frac{DC \sin{x}}{\sin{100}}}{\sin{(80-x)}}= \frac{DC}{\sin{100}}$$
Then
$$\tan{x}=\frac{\sin{140} \sin{80} -\sin{100}\sin{40}}{\sin{140}-\sin{100} \cos{40} + \sin{140} \cos{80}} = \frac{0}{0}$$ !
What does this mean ?

Comment: You don't have enough information to determine $x^\circ$. Imagine a line through $A$ and $B$. The point $C$ can move along that line without changing any of the given data, but $x^\circ$ could be anywhere in between $0^\circ$ and $40^\circ$.

Comment: I thought so , because it gives in-determined value so it has many values @Umberto P

Comment: I missed the edit window: $\boldsymbol D$ can move along the line, not $C$.

Comment: It's incorrect, and somewhat confusing, to say $\sin 140$ when you mean $\sin 140^\circ$.

Comment: What is it that you try to find? What is given? For every x you may find a triangle.

Comment: In other words - every triangle with 100 angle will do.